# How to associate data to a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery object `$myObject` that contains the elements `el_1, el_2, ..., el_n`. Doing

```
$myObject.data('foo', 'bar');
```

will assign the value `'bar'` to the data property `foo` for each element `el_1, el_2, ..., el_n`. Instead, I would like to associate data to the jQuery object `$myObject` *as a single entity*.

I guess I could do

```
$myObject['foo'] = 'bar';
```

but this may cause collisions with other properties and methods of the jQuery object. Is there a "jQuery-safe way" to associate data with a jQuery object?

Comment: Instead of messing with the jquery object itself, why not wrap it: `mySuperObj = {jq: $myObject, data:['my super special data']}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store that data in your own object, using the jQuery object references as keys, then store that object in the document's data. Something like:

```
$.fn.objData = function(key, value) {
    var rootData = $(document).data("jQueryObjectData");
    if (!rootData) {
        $(document).data("jQueryObjectData", rootData = {});
    }
    var objData = rootData[this];
    if (!objData) {
        rootData[this] = objData = {};
    }
    if (typeof value === "undefined") {
        return objData[key];
    }
    objData[key] = value;
    return this;
};
```

Then you can use the method as expected:

```
$myObject.objData("foo", "bar");
```

And later:

```
var foo = $myObject.objData("foo");
```

Of course, `$myObject` must refer to the very same object in the two calls, as two distinct jQuery objects containing the same elements will still count as different keys.

A potential problem with this approach is that the root data object will keep a reference to the jQuery objects used as keys, thus preventing the garbage collector from disposing them. It might prove to be a issue depending on the number of jQuery objects you create and the way you use the method.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to wrap it in a container object.

```
containerObj = {jquery: $myObject, data: ['data']};
```